# AWS ECS Fargate Cloudformation Hanging on Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I'm having an issue with trying to put together and deploy a simple application to run in the AWS ECS service using Fargate.  I started with an example I found here:

[AWS ECS Cloudformation Example](https://github.com/1Strategy/fargate-cloudformation-example/blob/master/fargate.yaml)

My YAML looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: An example CloudFormation template for Fargate.

#
# From: https://github.com/1Strategy/fargate-cloudformation-example/blob/master/fargate.yaml
#
# aws cloudformation deploy --template-file fargate.yaml --stack-name ecs-fargate-stack --parameter-overrides file://parameters.json --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --region us-east-2
# aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name ecs-fargate-stack --region us-east-2
#

Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id

  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

  Certificate:
    Type: String
    # Update with the certificate ARN from Certificate Manager, which must exist in the same region.

  Image:
    Type: String
    # Update with the Docker image. "You can use images in the Docker Hub registry or specify other repositories (repository-url/image:tag)."
    
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
    # update with the name of the service
    Default: MyService

  ContainerPort:
    Type: Number
    Default: 8080

  LoadBalancerPort:
    Type: Number
    Default: 443

  HealthCheckPath:
    Type: String

  HealthCheckPort:
    Type: Number
    Default: 8080

  HostedZoneName:
    Type: String

  Subdomain:
    Type: String
    Default: myservice

  # for autoscaling
  MinContainers:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1

  # for autoscaling
  MaxContainers:
    Type: Number
    Default: 5

  # target CPU utilization (%)
  AutoScalingTargetValue:
    Type: Number
    Default: 50

Resources:
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, Cluster]]

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    # Makes sure the log group is created before it is used.
    DependsOn: LogGroup
    Properties:
      # Name of the task definition. Subsequent versions of the task definition are grouped together under this name.
      Family: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TaskDefinition]]
      # awsvpc is required for Fargate
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      # 256 (.25 vCPU) - Available memory values: 0.5GB, 1GB, 2GB
      # 512 (.5 vCPU) - Available memory values: 1GB, 2GB, 3GB, 4GB
      # 1024 (1 vCPU) - Available memory values: 2GB, 3GB, 4GB, 5GB, 6GB, 7GB, 8GB
      # 2048 (2 vCPU) - Available memory values: Between 4GB and 16GB in 1GB increments
      # 4096 (4 vCPU) - Available memory values: Between 8GB and 30GB in 1GB increments
      Cpu: 256
      # 0.5GB, 1GB, 2GB - Available cpu values: 256 (.25 vCPU)
      # 1GB, 2GB, 3GB, 4GB - Available cpu values: 512 (.5 vCPU)
      # 2GB, 3GB, 4GB, 5GB, 6GB, 7GB, 8GB - Available cpu values: 1024 (1 vCPU)
      # Between 4GB and 16GB in 1GB increments - Available cpu values: 2048 (2 vCPU)
      # Between 8GB and 30GB in 1GB increments - Available cpu values: 4096 (4 vCPU)
      Memory: 0.5GB
      # A role needed by ECS.
      # "The ARN of the task execution role that containers in this task can assume. All containers in this task are granted the permissions that are specified in this role."
      # "There is an optional task execution IAM role that you can specify with Fargate to allow your Fargate tasks to make API calls to Amazon ECR."
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      # "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that grants containers in the task permission to call AWS APIs on your behalf."
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref ServiceName
          Image: !Ref Image
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          # Send logs to CloudWatch Logs
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs

  # A role needed by ECS
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, ExecutionRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'

  # A role for the containers
  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TaskRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'

      # ManagedPolicyArns:
      #   -
      # Policies:
      #   -

  # A role needed for auto scaling
  AutoScalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, AutoScalingRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceAutoscaleRole'

  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, ContainerSecurityGroup]]
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          ToPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup

  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, LoadBalancerSecurityGroup]]
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref LoadBalancerPort
          ToPort: !Ref LoadBalancerPort
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    # This dependency is needed so that the load balancer is setup correctly in time
    DependsOn:
      - ListenerHTTPS
    Properties: 
      ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 0
        MaximumPercent: 200
      DesiredCount: 2
      # This may need to be adjusted if the container takes a while to start up
      HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds: 120
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration: 
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          # change to DISABLED if you're using private subnets that have access to a NAT gateway
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref SubnetA
            - !Ref SubnetB
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Ref ServiceName
          ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckEnabled: true
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 90
      # will look for a 200 status code by default unless specified otherwise
      HealthCheckPath: !Ref HealthCheckPath
      HealthCheckPort: !Ref HealthCheckPort
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 2
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Name: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TargetGroup]]
      Port: !Ref ContainerPort
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: 60 # default is 300
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  ListenerHTTPS:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: !Ref LoadBalancerPort
      Protocol: HTTPS
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: !Ref Certificate

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        # this is the default, but is specified here in case it needs to be changed
        - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
          Value: 60
      Name: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, LoadBalancer]]
      # "internal" is also an option
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      Subnets:
        - !Ref SubnetA
        - !Ref SubnetB

  DNSRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: !Join ['', [!Ref HostedZoneName, .]]
      Name: !Join ['', [!Ref Subdomain, ., !Ref HostedZoneName, .]]
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
        HostedZoneId: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.CanonicalHostedZoneID

  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Join ['', [/ecs/, !Ref ServiceName, TaskDefinition]]

  AutoScalingTarget:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget
    Properties:
      MinCapacity: !Ref MinContainers
      MaxCapacity: !Ref MaxContainers
      ResourceId: !Join ['/', [service, !Ref Cluster, !GetAtt Service.Name]]
      ScalableDimension: ecs:service:DesiredCount
      ServiceNamespace: ecs
      # "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role that allows Application Auto Scaling to modify your scalable target."
      RoleARN: !GetAtt AutoScalingRole.Arn

  AutoScalingPolicy:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, AutoScalingPolicy]]
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref AutoScalingTarget
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization
        ScaleInCooldown: 10
        ScaleOutCooldown: 10
        # Keep things at or lower than 50% CPU utilization, for example
        TargetValue: !Ref AutoScalingTargetValue

Outputs:
  Endpoint:
    Description: Endpoint
    Value: !Join ['', ['https://', !Ref DNSRecord]]
```

When I deploy everything gets created except for the AWS::ECS::Service resource.  That just hangs forever (well at least for a couple of hours that I've let it run).

The symptoms I see are that the Load Balancer targets are always showing "unhealthy":

[image: Unhealthy Targets]

And I see tasks being started, running for a while, and then being stopped and new ones restarted.

[image: tasks]

Then this:

[image: more tasks]

I do see the tasks logging normally in Cloudwatch but there is never any traffic to them.

I also took the same image and setup a single Task Definition for it and ran it as a Fargate task on the cluster and that works as expected.  It shows "Healthy" in the HealthCheck field.

I believe the problem is with the Load Balancer Healthcheck where it thinks the tasks are failing and keeps killing them and starting new ones endlessly.

The only thing that I've found that stops this process is to delete the stack in the AWS Cloudformation console.

This is my first attempt using ECS/Fargate with a Load Balancer so any assistance is greatly appreciated.  The container itself is just an Alpine image with JBoss 7.4 and a simple Java web application installed.  That works normally in Docker as well as a standalone ECS/Fargate task.

Comment: And you are sure that your container will return a `200` OK HTTP response to requests at the `http://hostname:8080/applicatoin/hello` URL? If you are, then check your VPC flow logs to see if the HTTP requests are actually making it from the load balancer to the containers, or if they are being denied for some reason.

Comment: In addition to what Mark said, where did you put your tasks? Is it public or private subnet? I had issue when they were in a private subnet without NAT gateway

Comment: @MarkB Yes, I'm sure and when I run the same image as a standalone Fargate task (i.e. without the LB) it works and the healthcheck is normal.  When the healthcheck URL is requested there should be a log entry which there is running "naked" but there is not when running behind the LB.

Comment: @Caldazar Can you please elaborate on "where did you put your tasks"?  The entire Cloudformation is above but I'm not sure what you're asking me.

Comment: @jwh20 Private or public subnet?

Comment: The you need to check your VPC flow logs to look for traffic from the load balancer going to the ECS task, and see why it is being blocked.

Comment: @MarkB I enabled the VPC Flow Logs and now I need some help interpreting what I'm seeing there.  What am I looking for?  There are a lot of entries, some saying ACCEPT and others saying REJECT.

Comment: @Caldazar  In looking at the subnets, and there are two, what makes them public vs. private.  I don't see any attribute that says either public or private.

Comment: You need to look at the IP addresses assigned to the load balancer, and see if any of those are the source address of the REJECT records in the flow log.

Comment: A public subnet has a route to an Internet Gateway. A private subnet has a route to a NAT Gateway. An isolated subnet doesn't have a route to either of those. The public/private subnet thing doesn't seem relevant to the load balancer health check issue though.